# How do I import both student and parent information together?

Tags: import

I am trying to find out how to import student and parent information at the same time.  I have seen instructions about importing student and then adding the parent information afterwards, but I have a school roll of over 1000 students and adding parent information manually afterwards would take forever!!

Thanks for any assistance.

Steve

Answer (score 3):

No need to do this manually! Providing that you have a spreadsheet/data source that has all students and a parent/guardian column - so that you can create relationship during import. I'll try dig up a field mapping for you - and post it here shortly.

EDIT: found a wiki page for you: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Importing+Student,+Staff+and+Parents

PS - though tailored for CiviSchool - which is no longer supported - the import/mapping screens will show you how what import/mapping to use.

EDIT: highlighting the key screens from this Wiki - it's a two pass import:

***First: import the student:***

[image]

***Next: import the parent: key is Child of relationship to the Student:***

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that this is only for Drupal.  I am running in Wordpress.

Comment: The relevant bits for you here are the Mapping screenshots for the Contact import. They show you how to import relationships

Comment: Under the contact import for a student (under Wordpress), there are no mappings for parents.

Comment: Ok - so you need to go and make a Contact Subtype etc... You need to check/create the Relationships (perhaps add Guardian off e.g.) - CiviCRM does not ship with Students and Guardians as not all organizations use them. This has nothing to do with Wordpress - vs - Drupal.